# Mysql query to select record having same artistID but different CDID

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display the artist details once the album is selected. But at the same the other albums related to the artist should displayed too. Are there any way to achieve this.

[image]

The left column is the CDID and the right column is the artistID.

This is my current mysql code:

```
<?php

require "pdoDB.php";
$albumtitle = $_GET['title'];
$db = database::connect();
$artistsql = "SELECT a.artistName, p.pubName, cd.CDTitle FROM tiptop_artist a
             INNER JOIN tiptop_artistcd acd ON a.artistID = acd.artistID
             INNER JOIN tiptop_cd cd ON cd.CDID = acd.CDID 
             INNER JOIN tiptop_publisher p ON p.pubID = cd.pubID  
             WHERE cd.CDTitle = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($artistsql);
// $stmt->bindParam("catid", $categoryid);
$stmt->execute(array($albumtitle));

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Artist Name</th>
<th>Publisher</th>
<th>Other Album</th>
</tr>";

while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr style=\"cursor: pointer;\">";
    // echo "<td>" . $row1['artistName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['artistName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['pubName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['CDTitle'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```

The final output should obtain something like this:

```
artist name | publisher | related albums by the artist
------------------------------------------------------
hardwell    | sony music| I am hardwell
                        | Spaceman
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What table is the artists details stored in?

Comment: You should add an example of what the final output would be you are trying to obtain. Just a rough draft example with a few rows of data and where you want the details to show. So far you've showed us what you've done, but it's still not clear what output you are wanting.

Comment: ok i will edit my question once again

Comment: @prograhammer i have edite the question do take a look

Comment: Ok, gotcha...See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can accomplish this in a single query or in multiple queries. You may at one point need to compare different query strategies to see which is the most performant though.

*(Note: In the example below, you'll probably want to add a check after the first query to ensure it returns results before running the second query.)*

Here's an example using two queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT artist.name as 'artist.name', 
               artist.id as 'artist.id',
               publisher.name as 'publisher.name', 
               cd.title as 'cd.title',
               cd.id as 'cd.id'
        FROM tiptop_cd as cd
        INNER JOIN tiptop_artistcd as artistcd ON(artistcd.cd_id = cd.id)
        INNER JOIN tiptop_artist as artist ON(artist.id = artistcd.artist_id)
        INNER JOIN tiptop_publisher as publisher ON(publisher.id = cd.publisher_id)
        WHERE cd.title = :title";

$stmt = $db->prepare($artistsql);
$stmt->bindParam(":title", $_GET['title']);
$stmt->execute();
$details = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sql = "SELECT cd.title as 'cd.title'
        FROM tiptop_artistcd as artistcd
        INNER JOIN tiptop_cd as cd ON(cd.id = artistcd.cd_id AND cd.id != :cd_id)
        WHERE artistcd.artist_id = :artist_id";

$stmt = $db->prepare($artistsql);
$stmt->bindParam(":artist_id", $details['artist.id']);
$stmt->bindParam(":cd_id", $details['cd.id']);
$stmt->execute();

echo "<table>".
     "<tr>".
     "<th>Artist Name</th>".
     "<th>Publisher</th>".
     "<th>Other Album</th>".
     "</tr>".

     "<tr>".
     "<td>".$details['artist.name']."</td>".
     "<td>".$details['publisher.name']."</td>".
     "<td>".$details['cd.title']."</td>".
     "</tr>";

while ($album = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr style=\"cursor: pointer;\">";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $album['cd.title'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table";
```

Here's a single query version:

```
SELECT artist.name as 'artist.name', 
       publisher.name as 'publisher.name', 
       cd.title as 'cd.title',
       albums.title as 'albums.title'
FROM tiptop_cd as cd
INNER JOIN tiptop_artistcd as artistcd ON(artistcd.cd_id = cd.id)
INNER JOIN tiptop_artist as artist ON(artist.id = artistcd.artist_id)
INNER JOIN tiptop_publisher as publisher ON(publisher.id = cd.publisher_id)
INNER JOIN tiptop_artistcd as artistcd2 ON(artistcd2.artist_id = artist.id)
INNER JOIN tiptop_cd as albums ON(albums.id = artistcd2.cd_id)
WHERE cd.title = :title
```

Here's another clever (and possibly more performant) way to do it in a single query. The first row returned will contain your details and current selected cd, and the remaining rows the other albums:

```
SELECT artist.name as 'artist.name', 
       publisher.name as 'publisher.name', 
       cd.title as 'cd.title',
       IF(cd.title = :title, 1, 0) as selected
FROM tiptop_cd as cd
INNER JOIN tiptop_artistcd as artistcd ON(artistcd.cd_id = cd.id)
INNER JOIN tiptop_artist as artist ON(artist.id = artistcd.artist_id)
INNER JOIN tiptop_publisher as publisher ON(publisher.id = cd.publisher_id)
ORDER BY selected DESC
```

Comment: its displaying all the artist name.. i want it to display only the related albums to the artist only

Comment: i tried the first query but i am getting undefined offset 0

Comment: @anonymous5671 Oh, sorry, I've updated the answer. Just do `$details = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` directly.